# React Native notification image doesn't showing on IOS

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, notifications

I have currently a problem to display image in notification (with an url).
The problem is only on iOS, it works on Android.

I'm using React Native Firebase :

It works on Android but not in iOS.

**I have created the Notification Service and i have followed the react-native-firebase documentation and the image still doesn't appear.**

NotificationService.m

```
#import "NotificationService.h"
#import "FirebaseMessaging.h"

@interface NotificationService ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^contentHandler). 
(UNNotificationContent *contentToDeliver);
@property (nonatomic, strong) UNMutableNotificationContent 
*bestAttemptContent;

@end

@implementation NotificationService

- (void)didReceiveNotificationRequest:(UNNotificationRequest 
 *)request withContentHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationContent * 
 _Nonnull))contentHandler {
self.contentHandler = contentHandler;
self.bestAttemptContent = [request.content mutableCopy];

 [[FIRMessaging extensionHelper] 
 populateNotificationContent:self.bestAttemptContent 
 withContentHandler:contentHandler];
 }

 - (void)serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire {
// Called just before the extension will be terminated by the. 
system.
// Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at 
 modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be 
 used.
self.contentHandler(self.bestAttemptContent);
}

  @end
```

NotificationService.h

```
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface NotificationService : UNNotificationServiceExtension

@end
```

I received the notification json with the fcm_options (image) but it doesn't appear.

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/788sz.png)

[NotificationService.m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXLmt.png)

[NotificationService.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5j1lj.png)

[Notification Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94vYP.png)

[Notification Code Bis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fknvZ.png)

Thanks you.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem.

I have followed the react-native-firebase documentation
But when "NotivicationService" in my [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg1WK.png) is "ImageNotification" created by xcode, It's "OS Deployment Target" is different the main project "Sitesurveillance" "OS Deployment Target"

Before change ImageNotification target 15.2 and main project target 11.0.
I solved it by change "ImageNotification" > "Build Setting" > "OS Deployment Target" like the "Sitesurveiilance" > "Build Setting" > "OS Deployment Target" is 11.0

[this is my project build setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg1WK.png)

*Edited a bit for clarity*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Edited a bit for clarity